# MySQL select all components of a product

Tags: python, mysql, sql, select, mysql-python

I'm working for an automotive business. We have a table for our products with components of the product.

This is a tree-view of our one product. The part of a product makes E40 via assembly operation.
[image]

And this is the table-view from our MySQL database:

[image]

We want to get a result with the all components of the product. Like this:

> 'E40-1', 'E40-2', 'E40-3', 'E40-4', 'E40-5', 'E40-6', 'E40-6-1',
>   'E40-6-2'

So the results' lenght must be 8.

I have tried some MySQL queries but they don't work.

The queries that I tried:

```
select alt_bilesen from urunler_seviyeler where parcano in (select parcano from urunler_seviyeler where parcano="E40")
```

This give us only six part of the product. No E40-6-1 and no E40-6-2.
Also I tried:

```
select alt_bilesen from urunler_seviyeler where parcano in (select alt_bilesen from urunler_seviyeler where parcano="E40")
```

This give us only the lowest parts of the product. E40-6-1 and E40-6-2. Not the other parts.

By the way, we can use Python. If we want to use Python I think we must call it with some for loop, while loop, etc. Can you give me an advice? Thank you.

Comment: Is your expected output one row per product as you posted, or actually 8 rows? Also how many levels deep can your tree be (the product in your post has 2 levels, are there products with more levels than that?)

Comment: How deeply can the subproducts nest?  Only one level deep?

Comment: BrianDeMilia: We have more than 2 levels for some products.

GordonLinoff: It depends, we have 4 level deep products. If it has 1 level, we want to see only one level components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support "hierarchical" queries. It is possible to emulate that functionality, to a finite number of levels, using multiple queries. The results from the queries can be combined with a UNION ALL operation.

Getting the rows returned in a particular sequence can be problematic, depending on the actual criteria you need the rows returned.

First level:

```
SELECT t1.alt_bilesen
  FROM urunler_seviyeler t1 
 WHERE t1.parcano = 'E40'
```

Second level:

```
SELECT t2.alt_bilesen
  FROM urunler_seviyeler t1
  JOIN urunler_seviyeler t2
    ON t2.parcano = t1.alt_bilesen
 WHERE t1.parcano = 'E40'
```

Third level:

```
SELECT t3.alt_bilesen
  FROM urunler_seviyeler t1
  JOIN urunler_seviyeler t2 ON t2.parcano = t1.alt_bilesen
  JOIN urunler_seviyeler t3 ON t3.parcano = t2.alt_bilesen
 WHERE t1.parcano = 'E40'
```

Fourth level:

```
SELECT t4.alt_bilesen
  FROM urunler_seviyeler t1
  JOIN urunler_seviyeler t2 ON t2.parcano = t1.alt_bilesen
  JOIN urunler_seviyeler t3 ON t3.parcano = t2.alt_bilesen
  JOIN urunler_seviyeler t4 ON t4.parcano = t3.alt_bilesen
 WHERE t1.parcano = 'E40'
```

It is possible to combine the queries with `UNION ALL` set operators

```
( SELECT t1.alt_bilesen
    FROM urunler_seviyeler t1 
   WHERE t1.parcano = 'E40'
)
UNION ALL
( SELECT t2.alt_bilesen
    FROM urunler_seviyeler t1
    JOIN urunler_seviyeler t2
      ON t2.parcano = t1.alt_bilesen
   WHERE t1.parcano = 'E40'
)
UNION ALL
( SELECT t3.alt_bilesen
   FROM urunler_seviyeler t1
   JOIN urunler_seviyeler t2 ON t2.parcano = t1.alt_bilesen
   JOIN urunler_seviyeler t3 ON t3.parcano = t2.alt_bilesen
  WHERE t1.parcano = 'E40'
) 
UNION ALL
( SELECT t4.alt_bilesen
    FROM urunler_seviyeler t1
    JOIN urunler_seviyeler t2 ON t2.parcano = t1.alt_bilesen
    JOIN urunler_seviyeler t3 ON t3.parcano = t2.alt_bilesen
    JOIN urunler_seviyeler t4 ON t4.parcano = t3.alt_bilesen
   WHERE t1.parcano = 'E40'
)
ORDER BY 1
```

---

It's possible to include an additional "level" column, by including a literal value in each query. To get some ordering by something other than returned column, you'd need to include some additional expressions in each query...

Comment: To get this result for all (or more than one) `parcano`, rather than just one, include `t1.parcano` in the SELECT list, and remove (or modify) the predicate (i.e. condition in the WHERE clause) on `t1.parcano`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the part number itself:

```
select alt_bilesen
from urunler_seviyeler
where CONCAT(parcano, '-') like 'E40-%'
```

The `CONCAT()` prevents E400 from being confused with E40.

Otherwise, you need to start using `join`s.  And, if the sub-parts can nest deeply, you have a problem.  MySQL does not provide support in queries for hierarchical or nested data structures.

Comment: Good but we have some product like named X but its component not starts with X.

Answer (score 1):

This will go 3 more levels deep than in your example, but will also work for products with fewer levels, as in your example. You can add to the query if needed (if any products have more than 4 levels):

**Fiddle demonstration:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/681368/1/0

```
select t.parcano,
       trim(both ', ' from
            concat(group_concat(distinct t.alt_bilesen order by
                                t.alt_bilesen separator ', '),
                   ', ',
                   ifnull(concat(group_concat(distinct l1.alt_bilesen order by
                                              l1.alt_bilesen separator ', '),
                                 ', '),
                          ''),
                   ', ',
                   ifnull(concat(group_concat(distinct l2.alt_bilesen order by
                                              l2.alt_bilesen separator ', '),
                                 ', '),
                          ''),
                   ', ',
                   ifnull(concat(group_concat(distinct l3.alt_bilesen order by
                                              l3.alt_bilesen separator ', '),
                                 ', '),
                          ''),
                   ', ',
                   ifnull(concat(group_concat(distinct l4.alt_bilesen order by
                                              l4.alt_bilesen separator ', '),
                                 ', '),
                          '')

                   )) as parts
  from urunler_seviyeler t
  left join urunler_seviyeler x
    on x.alt_bilesen = t.parcano
  left join urunler_seviyeler l1
    on t.alt_bilesen = l1.parcano
  left join urunler_seviyeler l2
    on l1.alt_bilesen = l2.parcano
  left join urunler_seviyeler l3
    on l2.alt_bilesen = l3.parcano
  left join urunler_seviyeler l4
    on l3.alt_bilesen = l4.parcano
 where x.parcano is null
 group by t.parcano
```

To produce one row for each part rather than an aggregated list (which is what you put as the expected output in your question), you can create a view denormalizing the data:

```
create denorm_vw as
select t.parcano,
       t.alt_bilesen as l0,
       l1.alt_bilesen as l1,
       l2.alt_bilesen as l2,
       l3.alt_bilesen as l3,
       l4.alt_bilesen as l4
  from urunler_seviyeler t
  left join urunler_seviyeler x
    on x.alt_bilesen = t.parcano
  left join urunler_seviyeler l1
    on t.alt_bilesen = l1.parcano
  left join urunler_seviyeler l2
    on l1.alt_bilesen = l2.parcano
  left join urunler_seviyeler l3
    on l2.alt_bilesen = l3.parcano
  left join urunler_seviyeler l4
    on l3.alt_bilesen = l4.parcano
 where x.parcano is null;
```

And then run:

```
select parcano, l0 from denorm_vw union 
select parcano, l1 from denorm_vw where l1 is not null union 
select parcano, l2 from denorm_vw where l2 is not null union 
select parcano, l3 from denorm_vw where l3 is not null union 
select parcano, l4 from denorm_vw where l4 is not null
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd5a4/4/0

Comment: It's great. Is it possible to see result with multiple rows with one row for every component? Like the spencer7593's answer?

Comment: @Rictrunks That's why I asked in the comments whether you wanted 1 row or 8 rows. Yes, you can use this method to produce 8 rows. See above. But it would be easiest if you create a view on account of there being no with clause in MySQL.